# How do I stop a freezing Chrome?

Tags: macos

I tried Esc+Opt+Cmd, then selected Chrome and Force stop.
The name of the application dissapeared from that menu, but it was still freezed.
After 10 minutes I tried to reboot, but the computer were waiting for the application to close. In the end I pressed the power button for a couple of seconds to force the shutdown. Can I kill a lazy app without force-shutting down the mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the terminal type :

```
killall -9 Google\ Chrome
```

Since Google Chrome uses multiple process it will kill all the process of the app with that command.